# Google Drive API : Can't delete file

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I want to use Google Drive API to manage files programaticaly.
To do that, I use `ID clients OAuth 2.0 Web Application`. In `OAuth consent screen (Edit App)`, I check `.../auth/drive` and `.../auth/drive.readonly` scopes.

I'm log in, I have `token.json` file. I can list and download files

Now, when I want to delete file, I do this in python : `service.files().delete(fileId=item['id']).execute()`. But I have this issue :

```
An error occurred: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/<fileID>? returned "The user has not granted the app <appID> write access to the file <fileID>.". Details: "[{'message': 'The user has not granted the app <appID> write access to the file <fileID>.', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'appNotAuthorizedToFile', 'location': 'Authorization', 'locationType': 'header'}]">
```

What I do wrong ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Remove the `readonly` scope

Comment: in the future please include your code

Answer (score 1):

The scopes declared in Google cloud console are mainly for use with verification of your application.  Its your code that defines what scopes your application is requesting of the user.

I am going to assume that you are following the [Quick start for python](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/python) or [quick start for node.js](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/nodejs) both use token.json for credential storage.  The answer is the same either way.

This sample shows you how to use the [files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) method which allows for a readonly scope.

[image]

While the [file.delete](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/delete) does not allow for a readonly scope it requires write access.

[image]

## Fix

In the code you can see that the scope is readonly

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']
```

This means that when the user authorized your app they authorized it with a readonly scope giving you access to read the files only.  This the users credentials are now stored in token.json

To fix your issue change the scope to

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']
```

Then delete the token.json file and your app should now be resting full drive access giving you the ability to make changes like delete the files.

Comment: the second "SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']" should be different somehow, I guess.